# ApiDemo conflicts to other app on Nexus 4

Tags: android

I newly bought a Nexus 4 phone. I install SDK 4.2 version of ApiDemo app via my Eclipse, it ran well. But after I installed a third party app from Google Play, say AppA, ApiDemo stoped working. After a ran ApiDemo, it showed only an empty list. And if a tapped on the empty list, system dialog showed "AppA stopped". It's really weird. Then I tried to uninstall AppA, ApiDemo came back to working well.

What might lead to that problem? Given I cannot modify AppA, but I really need it. Can I modify something in ApiDemo to make to co-exist with AppA on my phone?

The following are all output from logcat when I get the empty list of ApiDemo:

```
07-01 15:39:17.813: D/dalvikvm(31248): GC_CONCURRENT freed 52K, 1% free 9145K/9228K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 25ms
07-01 15:39:17.813: D/dalvikvm(31248): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
07-01 15:39:17.873: D/dalvikvm(31248): GC_CONCURRENT freed 86K, 2% free 9473K/9592K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 19ms
07-01 15:39:17.953: D/libEGL(31248): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
07-01 15:39:17.953: D/libEGL(31248): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
07-01 15:39:17.963: D/libEGL(31248): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
07-01 15:39:17.963: I/Adreno200-EGL(31248): <eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic AU_full_mako_PARTNER-ANDROID/JB-MR1-DEV_CL2961380_release_AU (CL2961380)
07-01 15:39:17.963: I/Adreno200-EGL(31248): Build Date: 12/10/12 Mon
07-01 15:39:17.963: I/Adreno200-EGL(31248): Local Branch: 
07-01 15:39:17.963: I/Adreno200-EGL(31248): Remote Branch: m/partner-android/jb-mr1-dev
07-01 15:39:17.963: I/Adreno200-EGL(31248): Local Patches: NONE
07-01 15:39:17.963: I/Adreno200-EGL(31248): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
07-01 15:39:17.993: D/OpenGLRenderer(31248): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: check the logcat for "interesting" output around the time you get that empty list... might be useful to post the logcat

Comment: Maybe you could say what's the third party app AppA?

Comment: It's a local Chinese stock exchange app. So I guess it's not very meaningful to say exact name of the app.

Comment: It seems the heap is full. Something is leaking memory.

Comment: @StephanBranczykSt But AppA was actually not running. As long as AppA was installed, ApiDemo stopped working.